# Khyber's Harvest is made for how many PCs?

Tags: dnd-4e, published-adventures

I'm running the free adventure [Khyber's Harvest](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/4dnd/khybersharvest) but I can't find anywhere for how many PC's were the combat encounters designed. It says 750 XP should be awarded for the major quest and that PC's start at level 2 and end at level 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, all published 4e adventures are set up for 5 players.

If you want to be sure, just figure out how many XP the adventure dishes out (by adding up the major quest XP and all the encounters) and see if that's enough to get a 5 people party from level 2 to level 3, without reaching level 4.